# MySQL 'CASE' syntax on AFTER DELETE event trigger

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

I currently have a php script that removes a record from one table (active) and inserts it into another table (archive/history).

With this I'm writing an event trigger that will insert the same record again into the active table (its a reoccurring task) and then update the record's "duedate" field based on another field "Priority" within that same record.

I have all the logic on the php script completed, the issue is with the syntax in my event trigger. The error states **"Syntax error near '' at line 14 SQL command"**. (End statement). Also will this syntax update all records within the table or just the one that is replicated?

Trigger syntax here:

```
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO Tasks SELECT * FROM Tasks where taskName=taskName;

  UPDATE Tasks

  SET DueDate =

   CASE

    WHEN Priority = 'Daily' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)

    WHEN Priority = 'Weekly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)

    WHEN Priority = 'Monthly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

    WHEN Priority = 'Quarterly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)

    WHEN Priority = 'Bi-Yearly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

    WHEN Priority = 'Annually' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

   ELSE DueDate

END;
```

Comment: For clarification table name is "Tasks" and the PK is "taskName".

Comment: Can you give us full "CREATE" store procedure? I understand taskName is PK. How about the other taskName on the right side of =? Also what's your delimiter? I could be wrong, but as far as I know, delimiter should be different between (between BEGIN and END) and (outside of BEGIN and END). For example, `taskName=taskName;` and `END;` both should have different delimiters.

Comment: I'm using Adminr 3.3.3 and when creating an event trigger it gives you a little dropdown input form for the initial trigger syntax with the paremeters being Time, Event, and Type that denote (BEFORE/AFTER), (INSER,UPDATE,DELETE) AND (FOR EACH ROW) respectfully. The raw syntax generated looks like this:


DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `Tasks_ad` AFTER DELETE ON `Tasks` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 //sql statement and logic
END;;
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one END for BEGIN. You need 2 ENDs, one for CASE and another one for BEGIN.

```
DELIMITER ;; 
CREATE TRIGGER Tasks_ad AFTER DELETE ON Tasks FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tasks SELECT * FROM Tasks where taskName=taskName;
    UPDATE Tasks
    SET DueDate =
        CASE
            WHEN Priority = 'Daily' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            WHEN Priority = 'Weekly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
            WHEN Priority = 'Monthly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
            WHEN Priority = 'Quarterly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
            WHEN Priority = 'Bi-Yearly' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
            WHEN Priority = 'Annually' THEN DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
        ELSE DueDate
        END;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This syntax throws an error: ** Error in query: Syntax error near '; DELIMITER' at line 15** . Even if I manually change the delimiter sign to $$ it throws the same error at line 16 **Error in query: Syntax error near 'DELIMITER' at line 16**.

Comment: My bad, typo, I made two BEGINs :( Updated the answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help, pretty new to event triggers and I'm not 100% on the syntax yet.